# find_by_sql in Rails, accessing the resulting array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a query in a very quick and dirty way in Rails, without putting the rest of the model in place.  I know this is bad practice but I just need a quick result in a tight timeframe until I've got the whole solution in place.

I've got items that have a shipping price, based on weight.  The weight is stored in the item, the price is stored in the table shipping_zone_prices, and all I currently do is look for the price relating to the first row where the weight is heavier than the item for sale:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def shipping_price
    item_id = self.id
    shipping_price = ShippingZonePrice.find_by_sql(
      "SELECT z.price as price
       FROM shipping_zone_prices z, items i
       WHERE i.id = '#{item_id}'
       AND z.weight_g > d.weight
       ORDER BY z.weight_g asc limit 1")    
  end
end
```

This sort of works.  The SQL does the job, but when plugged into the app as follows:

```
 <%= @item.shipping_price %> Shipping
```

I get the following displayed:

```
[#<ShippingZonePrice price: 12>] Shipping
```

In this example, '12' is the price that is being pulled from the db, and is correct.  @item.shipping_price.class returns 'Array'.  Trying to access the array using [0] (or any other integer) returns a blank.

Is there another way to access this, or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Well spotted, that should be i.weight - I was just trying to make the data a bit generic by using 'item' and I didn't make all the correct changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are defining an instance method, I think it should return the `price` if it exists or `nil`

Try something like this:

```
def shipping_price
  ShippingZonePrice.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT z.price as price
     FROM shipping_zone_prices z, items i
     WHERE i.id = '#{self.id}'
     AND z.weight_g > d.weight
     ORDER BY z.weight_g asc limit 1").first.try(:price)
end
```

Then this should work for you:

```
@item.shipping_price
```

The `first.try(:price)` part is needed because `find_by_sql` may return an empty array. If you tried to do something like `first.price` on an empty array, you would get an exception along the lines of `NoMethodError: undefined method 'price' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `find_by_sql` returns a model, not data. If you want to do a direct fetch of the data in question, use something like this:

```
ShippingZonePrice.connection.select_value(query)
```

There are a number of direct-access utility methods available through `connection` that can fetch single values, a singular array, rows of arrays, or rows of hashes. Look at the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_value) for  `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements`.

As when writing an SQL directly, you should be very careful to not create SQL injection bugs. This is why it is usually best to encapsulate this method somewhere safe. Example:

```
class ShippingZonePrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.price_for_item(item)
    self.connection.select_value(
      self.sanitize_sql(
        %Q[
          SELECT z.price as price
            FROM shipping_zone_prices z, items i
            WHERE i.id=?
              AND z.weight_g > d.weight
            ORDER BY z.weight_g asc limit 1
        ],
        item.id
      )
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@item.shipping_price.first.price
```

or

```
@item.shipping_price[0].price
```

Thanks Atastor for pointing that out!

When you use `AS price` in `find_by_sql`, `price` becomes a property of the result.

Answer (score 1):

If not for you saying that you tried and failed accessing `[0]` i'ld say you want to put

```
@item.shipping_price.first.price # I guess BSeven just forgot the .first. in his solution
```

into the view...strange

Answer (score 1):

So, I had a hacky solution for this, but it works great.
Create a table that has the same output as your function and reference it, then just call a function that does a find_by_sql to populate the model.

Create a dummy table:

```
CREATE TABLE report.compliance_year (
 id BIGSERIAL,
 year TIMESTAMP,
 compliance NUMERIC(20,2),
 fund_id INT);
```

Then, create a model that uses the empty table:

```
class Visualization::ComplianceByYear < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'report.compliance_year'
    def compliance_by_year(fund_id)
        Visualization::ComplianceByYear.find_by_sql(["
            SELECT year, compliance, fund_id
              FROM report.usp_compliance_year(ARRAY[?])", fund_id])
    end
end
```

In your controller, you can populate it:

```
def visualizations
  @compliancebyyear = Visualization::ComplianceByYear.new()
  @compliancefunds = @compliancebyyear.compliance_by_year(current_group.id)
  binding.pry
end
```

Then, you can see it populate with what you need:

```
[1] pry(#<Thing::ThingCustomController>)> @compliancefunds
[
[0] #<Visualization::ComplianceByYear:0x00000008f78458> {
          :year => Mon, 31 Dec 2012 19:00:00 EST -05:00,
    :compliance => 0.93,
       :fund_id => 1
},
[1] #<Visualization::ComplianceByYear:0x0000000a616a70> {
          :year => Tue, 31 Dec 2013 19:00:00 EST -05:00,
    :compliance => 0.93,
       :fund_id => 4129
},
[2] #<Visualization::ComplianceByYear:0x0000000a6162c8> {
          :year => Wed, 31 Dec 2014 19:00:00 EST -05:00,
    :compliance => 0.93,
       :fund_id => 4129
}
]
```