# Use Raw mysql retrieve data from ruby on rails get unexpected

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to retrieve status data from table projects in ror project.

the mysql code will be :

`Setect status from projects where id = 2;`

Im new to ror so I try use raw mysql to retrieve data:

`sta1=Project.find_by_sql(["SELECT status FROM projects WHERE id = ?",id1]).first`

This returns a #

I'm expecting a string either "on" or "off"

whats my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [find\_by\_sql in Rails, accessing the resulting array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496967/find-by-sql-in-rails-accessing-the-resulting-array)

Comment: I think you just need `...first.status`.

Comment: Incidentally, you probably never want to use find_by_sql when there is a 'Rails way' of doing this... `sta1 = Project.find(id1).status` is where'd you go if you're finding by id...

Comment: Most (almost all) queries can be written without raw SQL, so consider that thing a last resort. Even if standard `ActiveRecord` snippets you can find are not enough for you, you can use `arel` that defines queries similarly to SQL but with possibility to use Ruby in constructing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pluck to get a single value out of the record.  It returns an array.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

```
Project.where(id: id1).pluck(:status).first
```